# How to read an enumerable without a loop without losing its scope?

Tags: c#, scope, ienumerable

I'm facing a pretty weird construct. The Foo type returned in an IEnumerable loses its data as soon as the enumeration ends. This means that I can't do a enumeration.First() because the data would be lost right away.

A loop over it works, but since I know it will contain only a single element that would be weird.

```
int Test(out int something)
    IEnumerable<Foo> enumeration = ...
    for (var foo in enumeration) {
        something = foo.GetSomething ();
        return foo.GetAnInt ();
    }
    something = 42;
    return 0;
}
```

Another way I though of is abusing a Linq Select, but that's just as horrible.

Is there a way to work around this limitation? Fixing the root cause is obviously superior, but difficult in this case.

**Edit:** It's an `IEnumerable<IDataRecord>` that is `yield returned` from a transactioned SQL data reader.

```
public IEnumerable<IDataRecord> ExecuteReader (SqlCommand cmd)
{
    using (var con = GetConnection()) {
        con.Open ();

        using (var tr = con.BeginTransaction ()) {
            cmd.Connection = con;

            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader ();
            while (reader.Read ()) {
                yield return reader;
            }

            tr.Commit ();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: whuuut..?! `void int` as return-type? i doubt you'll get an answer without more insight!

Comment: Is it possible to reword your question?

Comment: "How to read an enumerable without a loop" ... when you read a collection with a `for`, you'll always do a loop ... man, it's called for-**loop** :)

Comment: I get the OP's question title, I just don't get any of the code, or why the enumeration would go out of scope when you call `enumeration.First()`.

Comment: give us some code of `Foo` - maybe there's something special about this class ... or where do the instances come from? db? text-file? ... **MORE INFORMATION!!**

Comment: Probably the data gets cleaned up after the enumerator gets disposed. Please post the code of the iterator method that executes the SQL and returns that `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @mafutrct still too less informative ... until somebody else had been in the very same scenario, nobody can help you ... this just is too less to shad light on this weird issue! all we can do right now is guessing...

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair: Edited again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your `ExecuteReader` method does simply return the `SqlDataReader` itself (which implements `IDataRecord`), instead of returning a block of data. So when you do this:

```
var list = ExecuteReader(...).ToList();
```

In that case all elements of the list will be the same `SqlDataReader` instance, but after the `ToList` has been executed, the reader has been closed. I'm a bit surprised that you don't get an `ObjectDisposedException`.

For this to work, you need to return a copy of the data in the `IDataRecord`. You think you can iterate the elements in the data record. An other option is to change the `ExecuteReader` to the following:

```
public IEnumerable<T> ExecuteReader<T>(SqlCommand cmd, 
    Func<IDataRecord, T> recordCreator)
{
    using (var con = GetConnection()) {
        con.Open ();

        using (var tr = con.BeginTransaction()) {
            cmd.Connection = con;

            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read()) {
                yield return recordCreator(reader);
            }

            tr.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

This way you can do the following:

```
var list = ExecuteReader(command, record => new
{
    Item1 = record.GetInt("id"),
    Item2 = record.GetString("name")
});
```

Note: I'm not sure why you need a transaction for this anyway.

Comment: This is probably the cleanest solution.

Comment: Btw, in hindsight I am surprised about the missing ObjectDisposedException, too. Rest assured that this, and the various deadlocks I encountered when trying to bend Linq to my will, was interesting to debug.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
int Test(out int something)
{
    IEnumerable<Foo> enumeration = ...
    var values = enumeration
        .Select(foo => new
                {
                    something = foo.GetSomething(),
                    anInt = foo.GetAnInt()
                })
        .FirstOrDefault();
    if (values != null)
    {
        something = values.something;
        return values.anInt;
    }
    else
    {
        something = 42;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

`GetSomething` and `GetAnInt` are called while inside the enumeration.

Comment: well thought! extracting the needed values on iteration is very clever!

Comment: I'm still not sure I follow why this is needed and why it works, but if it _does_ work, good :)

Comment: @Rawling: Note that the code with the weird for loop I posted in the question works, too, but both ways are not exactly brilliant - it's really just abusing language features.

Comment: @Rawling I noticed this actually doesn't work: An out parameter cannot be used inside a lambda.

Comment: @mafutrct Is that because the `something` in my anonymous type has the same name as the `out something` parameter? I didn't expect that to be the case, but you could always use `Something` and `AnInt` instead if so.

Comment: @Rawling: Oh, of course! My mistake, I eat my words, your method does work. I should consult an actual compiler before speaking.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea could be to convert the result type of the method from IEnumerable to IEnumerator. That way, scope control is much easier, and returning single results does not require any (fake) loop, too.

**Edit:** I think I found a way to refactor the whole issue. This circumvents the initial problem by using new disposable class that contains the logic formerly found in the method. It's very readable and less code even.

```
public TransactedConnection GetConnection (string text)
{
    return new TransactedConnection (_ConnectionString, text);
}

public class TransactedConnection : IDisposable
{
    private readonly SQLiteCommand _Cmd;
    private readonly SQLiteConnection _Con;
    private readonly SQLiteTransaction _Tr;

    public TransactedConnection (string connection, string text)
    {
        _Cmd = new SQLiteCommand (text);
        _Con = new SQLiteConnection (connection);
        _Con.Open ();
        _Cmd.Connection = _Con;
        _Tr = _Con.BeginTransaction ();
    }

    public void Dispose ()
    {
        _Tr.Commit ();
        _Tr.Dispose ();
        _Con.Dispose ();
        _Cmd.Dispose ();
    }

    public SQLiteParameterCollection Parameters
    {
        get
        {
            return _Cmd.Parameters;
        }
    }

    public int ExecuteNonQuery ()
    {
        return _Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery ();
    }

    public object ExecuteScalar ()
    {
        return _Cmd.ExecuteScalar ();
    }

    public SQLiteDataReader ExecuteReader ()
    {
        return _Cmd.ExecuteReader ();
    }
}

public void Test (string match)
{
    var text = "SELECT * FROM Data WHERE foo=@bar;";

    using (var cmd = GetConnection (text)) {
        cmd.Parameters.Add ("@bar", DbType.String).Value = match;

        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader ()) {
            while (reader.Read ()) {
                Console.WriteLine (reader["foo"]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```